# When Worksharing Constructs Inside a critical Construct is useful in OpenMP?

Tags: c, openmp

Among OpenMP examples the following code can be found [6.2 Worksharing Constructs Inside a critical Construct](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-5-0-1.pdf):

```
void critical_work()
{
  int i = 1;
  #pragma omp parallel sections
  {
    #pragma omp section
    {
      #pragma omp critical (name)
      {
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
          #pragma omp single
          {
            i++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Have you ever used this structure? Under what circumstances is it the best option in real life? My only guess is that it can be useful in error handling, what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this particular example just demonstrates that this kind of code is still conforming with the standard.
If the question is just about having a worksharing construct inside a critical construct (inside a worksharing construct), I could roughly imagine hierarchical applications where you generally have two layers of nested OpenMP parallelism, but most work is done outside of the critical region, e.g.:

```
void mostly_uncritical_work()
{
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
      /* main workload */
    }
    #pragma omp critical (name)
    {
      #pragma omp parallel
      {
        /* smaller amount of work but still big enough */
        /* to profit from parallelization */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So in the end the question boils down to "Are there applications for nested OpenMP parallelism?" and there my answer would certainly be yes. I use it for example to have a team of 2 threads in the outer team, one of them simulating things on a GPU and the other one analyzing the output of the GPU using an inner team of threads.

Comment: Thank you, indeed, my question was about having a worksharing construct inside a critical construct. When I first saw this structure, it was very strange to me, but now it makes sense..